# How to scroll beyond the last cell in a UITableView or UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

I want a tableView (and collectionView) to scroll beyond the last cell.
That is, when scrolling, and you reach the last cell, I want the tableView to continue scrolling for lets say 200 points more past the last cell.

I tried:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 200, right: 0)
```

But the behaviour of this code just like changing the frame (The whole tableView move up 200 points). Which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a table view you can add a view of the desired height as the table view's footer.

```
let footer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 200))
self.tableView.tableFooterView = footer
```

Depending on the look, you may want to set the background color of the footer view.

For a collection view you can setup a section footer for the last section of the collection view.

Answer (score 1):

**Collection View**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    // Section Insets
}
```

There is no straight forward way to do this with a `UITableView`, but you can create a footer view with `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int)` and use the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int)` to add extra height to the last section giving that scrolling effect.

Comment: This method also lifts the collectionView up, not increasing the scrollable area which what I want.

Comment: What do you mean you want to increase the scrollable area? Like the increase the frame size of the scroll view?

Comment: Yes, something like that. I have a full-screen tableView but also have an overlying button at the bottom. So the last row appears behind this button. What I want is to let the tableView to scroll down more so that the last cell appears above the button.

Comment: You can do that by creating a footer view for the last section. Make it the width of the table view, and set the height manually to whatever you want. This can be a clear view, making it look like the table view is over scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach using Size inspector.

- Select collection View in xib or storyboard, go to size inspector.
- Set value in Footer Size to 30 40 or as per your need.
- Run it.

Scroll now works beyond actual height of collection view.